# Python combining items in a list of lists python

Tags: python, list, combinations

I have three items in a list of lists:

```
test = [[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]
```

I want it to look like this:

```
test = [[a,b,c,d,e,f],[g,h,i]]
```

what is the best way to do this in python?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I guess there is a typo in your example.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> test = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
>>> test[0].extend(test.pop(1))  # OR  test[0] += test.pop(1)
>>> test
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Can you use pop for a range? say if I wanted to combine all 3 could I write: test[0].extend(test.pop(1:2))

Comment: @EnglishGrad, No, `list.pop` does not accept a range.

Comment: So what would I do if I wanted to put the 3 lists together? just use the + like stated below?

Comment: @EnglishGrad, To get this: `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]` ?

Comment: @EnglishGrad, Using list comprehension: `[[x for xs in test for x in xs]]`. If you want a flat list: `[x for xs in test for x in xs]`

Comment: @EnglishGrad, See [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). BTW, list comprehension does not change the list inplace, but returns new list unlike the solution given in my answer.

Comment: @EnglishGrad: to get `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]`, use reduce: `[reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, test)]`

Comment: @njzk2, `[sum(test, [])]` is shorter. But I don't recommend them because both are not efficient; they create n or n-1 temporary lists.

Comment: I see to be getting lists of lists still when I combine them. How do I go from [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]] to [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]?

Comment: @EnglishGrad, Why don't use simply use this? `[x for xs in test for x in xs]`

Answer (score 2):

```
test = [test[0] + test[1], test[2]]
```

Comment: You mean `[test[0]+...`, not `[list[0]+...`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to flatten of an arbitrary slice, use a slice assignment and a list comprehension on the part you want to flatten.

This flatten from position `n` to end of the list:

```
>>> test = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15]]
>>> n=2
>>> test[n:]=[[i for s in test[n:] for i in s]]
>>> test
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

This flattens up to `n` (but including `n`):

```
>>> test = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15]]
>>> test[0:n]=[[i for s in test[0:n] for i in s]]
>>> test
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
```

This flattens in the middle (from and including `n` to include the additional groups specified):

```
>>> test = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15]]
>>> test[n:n+2]=[[i for s in test[n:n+2] for i in s]]
>>> test
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
```

Flatten all the sublists:

```
>>> test = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15]]
>>> n=len(test)
>>> test[0:n]=[[i for s in test[0:n] for i in s]]
>>> test
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Note that in each case the slice on the assignment side is the same as the slice on the list comprehension side. This allows the use of the same [slice object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) for each.

For the last case of flattening the whole list, obviously, you can just do `test=[[i for s in test for i in s]]` but the fact the logic is consistent allows you to wrap this in a function use a slice object.

Comment: This is awesome @dawg

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the first two items in the list of list with the `+` operator and you should use `''` for your strings

```
test = [['a','b','c'],['e','f','g'],['h','i','j']]
result = [test[0] + test[1], test[2]]
print result

output:
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['h', 'i', 'j']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) package:

```
import more_itertools as mit

list(mit.chunked(mit.flatten(test), 6))
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```